# need to add to this LIKE clause on IBM i SQL

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a VIEW with these WHERE Conditions. I would like to add another type on the 3 rd line here
I want also those rows with like as "FR" is there a way to sort of have such a group like that under the LIKE clause?

```
ASTDTA.ICPRTMIA.IARCC9='ACS' AND        
ASTDTA.OEINDLID.IDCOM#='001' AND        
ASTDTA.OEINDLID.IDPRT# LIKE 'ACS%' AND  
ASTDTA.ADRESSAD.ADSFX# =                
SUBSTR(ASTDTA.OEINDLID.IDGRC#,9,3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an OR condition:

```
ASTDTA.ICPRTMIA.IARCC9='ACS' AND        
ASTDTA.OEINDLID.IDCOM#='001' AND        
(ASTDTA.OEINDLID.IDPRT# LIKE 'ACS%' OR ASTDTA.OEINDLID.IDPRT# LIKE 'FR%') AND  
ASTDTA.ADRESSAD.ADSFX# =                
SUBSTR(ASTDTA.OEINDLID.IDGRC#,9,3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've only got a small handful of patterns, then use JamesA's answer. But if you find you have a bunch, then put your patterns in a table, or a temp table, or possibly just a common table expression with a values statement in it. Let's call it RULES. Now you can join to it, and say

```
ASTDTA.OEINLID.IDPRT# LIKE RULES.PATTERN
```

Comment: but make sure that Rules.Pattern is a VARCHAR or your rules have to pad on the right with % signs.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy : Such padding is really only needed when constructing the LIKE condition from variables. With literal constants, it's not a problem. I've never dug into why it makes a difference.

Comment: Well since the answer was talking about using a column for the pattern and NOT a literal... Anyway, it makes a difference for fixed length character variables or columns because the spaces on the end of the field become part of the like pattern. So if a varchar(5) column and a char(5) column each contain 'ABC%', the like pattern with the varchar column will be `'ABC%'` while the like pattern with the char column will be `'ABC% '` See the difference? Only the varchar pattern will match 'ABCDE' The char pattern will only match strings that start with 'ABC' and have a trailing blank!